# IBOutlet UITextView is nil after calling another class initWithNibName and back to the class using method

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

My problem is that in **ProductNote** class `UIButton` Action I did `initWithNibName` **Notes Class** to show the **popOver** with a `UITableView` in **Notes Class**. I am fetching data from `sqlite` and then load it to `UITableView` in `tableViewDidSelectRowAtindexPath:`. I got the **selectedNote** and creates object of **ProductNote Class** to call **selectedNote** instance method that only set **IBOutlet's** `textview.text` but its nil. Thats my problem, Below is the code please help me to knowing why i face this type of issue. I am using **Xcode 4.3.3** and not using **ARC**. Manually I defined dealloc method on every ViewController

```
//**ProductNote.h Class****************************
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Notes;
@interface ProductNote : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
UIPopoverController *popOverController;
UITextView *txtmesssagenotes;
Notes *objNotes;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtmesssagenotes; //It is Connected to ProductNote.xib
@property (retain,nonatomic)  UIPopoverController *popOverController; 
@property (retain,nonatomic)  Notes *objNotes;
-(IBAction)presentPopOver:(UIButton*)sender;
 -(void)selectedNote:(NSString*)note;
@end

//ProductNote.m Class
@implementation ProductNote
@synthesize txtmesssagenotes,popOverController,objNotes;

-(IBAction)presentPopOver:(UIButton*)sender
{
self.objNotes=[[Notes alloc]initWithNibName:@"Notes"bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController *popOver=[[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:objNotes]autorelease];
self.popOverController=popOver;
self.popOverController.delegate=self;
self.popOverController.popoverContentSize=objNotes.view.frame.size;
CGRect rect=[self.view convertRect:objNotes.view.frame fromView:self.view];
rect.origin.y+=110;
rect.origin.x+=23;
[self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
 //Then I get popOver with tableview 
}
-(void)selectedNote:(NSString*)note
{
 self.txtmesssagenotes.text=note;     
 //Here I am getting txtmesssagenotes=0X0 or nil. Using self or without self Please tell me the reason.
}
- (void)dealloc {
[txtmesssagenotes release];
[popOverController release];
[objNotes release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

---

```
@interface Notes : UITableViewController
{
NSMutableArray *arrNotes;
NSString *selectedNote;
UITableView *tblNotes;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arrNotes;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *selectedNote;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tblNotes;
@end

//Actually I skip the other methods that makes larger program to read . other methods only    used to fetch data from sqlite and fill up the arrNotes that is used to fill all rows in the  tableview. 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 self.selectedNote=[self.arrNotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

//Here self.arrNotes valid object and contains the data, and assigns NSString object to self.selectedNote

```
ProductNote *productNote=[[ProductNote alloc]init];
[productNote selectedNote:self.selectedNote]; //after calling selectedNote i goto to selectedNote implementation or definition above.
[productNote release];

}
-(void)dealloc
{
[arrNotes release];
[selectedNote release];
[tblNotes release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Why did I loose two reputation ?????????????

Comment: Because the text at the top of your question has no punctuation whatsoever and is horrible to read - try putting in line breaks and/or paragraphs :)

Comment: FYI: If you're creating a UIViewController subclass, call it `somethingViewController` - that way people reading your code will understand it faster :) e.g. `ProductNote` => `ProductNoteViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `selectedNote:` before your view has loaded?

Just because you created a view controller with a xib doesn't mean that it loads all your subviews immediately.

The xib is parsed and all your views are created the first time that the view controller's `view` property is asked for - this is usually just before it appears for the first time.

Until then, all the `IBOutlet` connections will be `nil`.

You need to store the text for your note as an `NSString` property of you view controller. Then, inside either `viewDidLoad` you need to call `self.txtmesssagenotes.text=self.note;` - `viewDidLoad` is automatically called just after your view is loaded so you are guaranteed to have all your `IBOutlet`s set by then.

You shouldn't rely on your view objects to store the state of your app (in this case, the text of the note). If a low memory warning is received while your view controller isn't visible then all your view objects will be deleted - they will only be recreated when your view controller becomes visible again - if you are storing your note string inside a UITextView then it might no be there the next time you ask for it :) You should always store data in a property of your view controller (or somewhere else you control) and create your views using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am loading Notes Class with initWithNibName then add it to popOverController. Could you please try to understand my question I have also commented it please check.

Comment: Your question (which you _still_ haven't formatted to make it easy to read) is __why is self.txtmesssagenotes nil?__. txtmessagenotes is in the `ProductNote` class which you create using `[[ProductNote alloc]init];` (taken from the last snippet of code in your question). Why do you expect it to come from a xib?

Comment: why is self.txtmesssagenotes nil? yeah thats my ques. txtmesssagenotes is IBoutlet of ProductNote that is displaying. I crete productNote class object in Notes class didselectrowatindexpath only to call selectedNote and set txtmesssagenotes.text.

Comment: Your properties are only created _after_ your view controler's view is loaded. You're calling `selectedNote:` _before_ your controller's view has been loaded. Just because you've created a view controller doesn't mean that you created all of it's views yet.

Comment: Sir I have already loaded my ProductNotes.xib that has a UIButton.By Clicking -(IBAction)presentPopOver:(UIButton*)sender called that Displays PopOver with Notes Class.xib over the ProductNotes Class.xib then I would like to set text of txtmessagenotes TextView of ProductNote Class. by calling selectedNote method of ProductNotes class. It get called but textview remains nil. Thank you very much for your time and interest for my question but seriously I face this type of issue moreover and give me headache.

Comment: Repeating the question won't help you understand our answers. You need to learn more about how UIViewControllers and UIViews interact with each other. In the last piece of code in your question you (a) create a new `ProductNote`, (b) _before it's view is loaded_ you call `selectedNote:` and (c) just release it without doing anything else to it. At no point to you display it. At no point do you get it to create it's view. Until you understand when view controllers create their views you're not going to understand why you have this bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is because just as you stated that txtmesssagenotes was created using IB.  And you never presented your ProductNote UIViewController instant productNote.  So the txtmesssagenotes was never allocated and initialized properly.

Comment: No Actually after Displaying View of ProductNote Class. There is a UiButton clicking on it I am loading Notes class in popover with tableview displaying some data on the product note class. When user tap any row in tableview I create ProductNote class object to access its selectedNote instance method then set ProductNote Class IBoutlet textmessagenotes.text but it nil.thats the big headache for me today

Comment: This line: [productNote selectedNote:self.selectedNote]; was used immediately after you just allocated the productNote.  So until you present/push your productNote to the display stack, all your outlets could not have been instantiated.  @deanWombourne's answer is very comprehensive.  I would study his answer completely.